# SendGrid SMTP emails are not delivered to CC and BCC addresses in Go

Tags: go, email, smtp, sendgrid

I am trying to send an email with CC & BCC. Emails are not delivered to CC & BCC addresses. But CC addresses are displayed to the recipient's details. A snapshot is given below.

[image]

I am using golang **net/smtp** with **SendGrid**. My code sample is given below.

```
func SendEmail() error {

        email := entity.Email{
        From:    "info@somewhere.cloud",
        To:      []string{"crajuceveifre-5717@yopmail.com"},
        ReplyTo: "dileulobugre-7335@yopmail.com",
        Subject: "Email Subject",
        Body:    "Email Body",
        BCC:     []string{"lecrecezufeu-9078@yopmail.com"},
        CC:      []string{"houcroissezitri-3721@yopmail.com"},
    }
    emailMessageBytes := ToBytes(email)

    smtpAuth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "apikey", config.Config.EmailClientApiKey, config.Config.EmailClientHost)

    err := smtp.SendMail(config.Config.EmailClientHost+":"+config.Config.EmailClientPort, smtpAuth, email.From, email.To, emailMessageBytes)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("smtp error: %s", err)
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func ToBytes(m entity.Email) []byte {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)

    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("From: %s\r\n", m.From))
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("To: %s\r\n", strings.Join(m.To, ",")))
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Reply-To: %s\r\n", m.ReplyTo))
    if len(m.CC) > 0 {
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Cc: %s\r\n", strings.Join(m.CC, ",")))
    }

    if len(m.BCC) > 0 {
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Bcc: %s\r\n", strings.Join(m.BCC, ",")))
    }
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Subject: %s\r\n", m.Subject))

    buf.WriteString("MIME-Version: 1.0\n")
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(buf)
    boundary := writer.Boundary()

    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s\n\n", boundary))
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("--%s\n", boundary))

    buf.WriteString("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n")
    buf.WriteString(m.Body)
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\n\n--%s\n", boundary))

    return buf.Bytes()
}
```

Please help me. Advance thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the covers, [smtp.SendMail](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.2:src/net/smtp/smtp.go;l=323) calls `smtp.Client.Rcpt` for each `to` recipient.
The `to` slice directs who will actually receive the email. The addressees in the body of the email is purely informational - in fact they don't even need to match the real addressee info.

So to fix your addressing issue, you need to collect all `to`, `cc` & `bcc` addressees:

```
var all []string
for _, a := range [][]string{email.To, email.CC, email.BCC} {
    all = append(all, a)
}

err := smtp.SendMail(
    config.Config.EmailClientHost+":"+config.Config.EmailClientPort,
    smtpAuth,
    email.From,
    all, //email.To,
    emailMessageBytes,
)
```

also since every recipient receives the body of the e-mail, `bcc` users should *not* be listed in the
body, for obvious privacy reasons.

So remove this:

```
// if len(m.BCC) > 0 {
//    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Bcc: %s\r\n", strings.Join(m.BCC, ",")))
//}
```

Comment: Working fine. Thanks